# python whatsapp chat remove invalid tokens

Tags: python, whatsapp

I want to analyze a WhatsApp Chat History.
I've split the text into the words. But I have the problem that there are many unnecessary words (I guess these are emojis for example).
Does anyone know how to check if a word is valid in Python? (That means that the word contains at least one character of the alphabet)

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty here is to properly define what constitutes a valid word. This can be arbitrarily complex when multiple languages need to be considered.

If you just want to check if the word contains at least one Ascii character, you can do this:

```
def is_valid_word(word):
  return any([letter in string.ascii_letters for letter in word])
```